# apt-mirror not cleaning after completion and how do I update existing local repo

Tags: repository, apt-mirror

I'm not new to linux, but I am to setting up a local repo. After doing some research on how to download and setup a local ubuntu repo, I decided to use apt-mirror to accomplish my mission. However, after the downloading process finished, I noticed that the clean.sh script didn't remove any files and the postmirror.sh couldn't be opened.

Here is what my mirror.list file looks like:

```
set base_path /home/userx/xenial_repo
set nthreads 30
set _tilde 0

deb-amd64 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse

clean http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu
```

I used the following command to execute apt-mirror and start the downloading process:

```
sudo apt-mirror /etc/apt/mirror.list
```

Here is the output after I executed the command above:

```
userx@machinex:~/xenial_repo$ sudo apt-mirror /etc/apt/mirror.list 
Downloading 104 index files using 30 threads...
Begin time: Fri Sep 16 23:12:25 2016
[30]... [29]... [28]... [27]... [26]... [25]... [24]... [23]... [22]... [21]... [20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Fri Sep 16 23:12:38 2016

Processing tranlation indexes: [TT]

Downloading 540 translation files using 30 threads...
Begin time: Fri Sep 16 23:12:38 2016
[30]... [29]... [28]... [27]... [26]... [25]... [24]... [23]... [22]... [21]... [20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Fri Sep 16 23:13:06 2016

Processing DEP-11 indexes: [DD]

Downloading 14 dep11 files using 14 threads...
Begin time: Fri Sep 16 23:13:06 2016
[14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Fri Sep 16 23:13:10 2016

Processing indexes: [SSPP]

168.6 GiB will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 160330 archive files using 30 threads...
Begin time: Fri Sep 16 23:13:24 2016
[30]... [29]... [28]... [27]... [26]... [25]... [24]... [23]... [22]... [21]... [20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Sat Sep 17 04:08:46 2016

0 bytes in 0 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /home/userx/xenial_repo/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

Running the Post Mirror script ...
(/home/userx/xenial_repo/var/postmirror.sh)

/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /home/userx/xenial_repo/var/postmirror.sh

Post Mirror script has completed. See above output for any possible errors.
```

After it finished downloading, I looked in the /home/userx/xenial_repo directory to see what was inside and I found the following structure:

```
xenial_repo
├───mirror
│   ├───archive.ubuntu.com
│   │   └───ubuntu
│   │       ├───dists
│   │       │   └───xenial-updates
│   │       │       ├───main
│   │       │       ├───multiverse
│   │       │       ├───restricted
│   │       │       └───universe
│   │       └───pool
│   │           ├───main
│   │           ├───multiverse
│   │           └───universe
│   └───mirror.symnds.com
│       └───ubuntu
│           ├───dists
│           │   └───xenial
│           │       ├───main
│           │       ├───multiverse
│           │       ├───restricted
│           │       └───universe
│           └───pool
│               ├───main
│               ├───multiverse
│               ├───restricted
│               └───universe
├───skel
│   ├───archive.ubuntu.com
│   │   └───ubuntu
│   │       └───dists
│   │           └───xenial-updates
│   │               ├───main
│   │               ├───multiverse
│   │               ├───restricted
│   │               └───universe
│   └───mirror.symnds.com
│       └───ubuntu
│           └───dists
│               └───xenial
│                   ├───main
│                   ├───multiverse
│                   ├───restricted
│                   └───universe
└───var
```

I noticed that both mirror and skel directories as similar with the exception that skel does not contain the pool directories which contain the deb files. The var directory contains a bunch of log files.

I'm trying to figure out which files I only need for my local repo and what I need to do in order to update the repo at least once a month.

So I have a few questions:

- Do I need the skel and var directories or can I remove them? It looks like the clean.sh script didn't remove anything, so I don't know what I should keep and what to delete.
- How do I perform an update to the local xenial repo without downloading all of the files again?
- Is it possible to change the ubuntu repo server location in the mirror.list file and still perform an update?
- Can I merge the content in both mirror.symnds.com and archive.ubuntu.com in the mirror directory?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make the 'ubuntu' directory in the Apache document root as well as some soft links for package and metadata locations.  If you navigate to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, you will see the structure we are trying to accomplish.

```
mkdir -p /var/www/html/ubuntu

ln -s /mnt/usb/repos/debian/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool /var/www/html/ubuntu/pool

ln -s /mnt/usb/repos/debian/skel/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists /var/www/html/ubuntu/dists
```